# i have no clue how to solve this issue in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to build a silly game however I'm stuck with an error here and I can't figure out the issue. please help me I'm new to Pygame? and it's my first game

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
from pygame.sprite import Group

pygame.init()

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
fps = 60

screen_width = 1400
screen_height = 1000
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((screen_width, screen_height))
pygame.display.set_caption('Radiation Lab')

tile_size = 50

class world():
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.tile_list = []

        # loade images
        dirt_image = pygame.image.load('images/dirt.png')
        dirt_l_image = pygame.image.load('images/dirt_l.jpg')

        row_count = 0
        for row in data:
            col_count = 0
            for tile in row:
                if tile == 1:
                    img = pygame.transform.scale(dirt_image, (tile_size, tile_size))
                    img_rect = img.get_rect()
                    img_rect.x = col_count * tile_size
                    img_rect.y = row_count * tile_size
                    tile = (img, img_rect)
                    self.tile_list.append(tile)
                if tile == 2:
                    img = pygame.transform.scale(dirt_l_image, (tile_size - 49, tile_size))
                    img_rect = img.get_rect()
                    img_rect.x = col_count * tile_size
                    img_rect.y = row_count * tile_size
                    tile = (img, img_rect)
                    self.tile_list.append(tile)
                if tile == 3:
                    rad = Radiation(col_count * tile_size, row_count * tile_size)
                    rad_group.add(Radiation)



                col_count += 1
            row_count += 1

    def drow(self):
        for tile in self.tile_list:
            screen.blit(tile[0], tile[1])


class player():
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.images_right = []
        self.images_left = []
        self.index = 0
        self.counter = 0
        for num in range(1, 11):
            img_right = pygame.image.load(f'images/guy{num}.png')
            img_right = pygame.transform.scale(img_right, (150, 300))
            img_left = pygame.transform.flip(img_right, True, False)
            self.images_right.append(img_right)
            self.images_left.append(img_left)
        self.image = self.images_right[self.index]
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y
        self.vel_y = 0
        self.jumped = False
        self.width = self.image.get_width()
        self.height = self.image.get_height()
        self.direction = 0

    def update(self):
        dx = 0
        dy = 0
        walk_cooldown = 10
        # key press
        key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if key[pygame.K_SPACE] and self.jumped == False:
            self.vel_y = - 15
            self.jumped = True
        if key[pygame.K_SPACE] == False:
            self.jumped = False
        if key[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            dx -= 1
            self.counter += 1
            self.direction = -1
        if key[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            dx += 1
            self.counter += 1
            self.direction = 1
        if key[pygame.K_RIGHT] == False and key[pygame.K_LEFT] == False:
            self.counter = 0
            self.index = 0
            if self.direction == 1:
                self.image = self.images_right[self.index]
            if self.direction == -1:
                self.image = self.images_left[self.index]


        # animation
        if self.counter > walk_cooldown:
            self.counter = 0
            self.index += 1
            if self.index >= len(self.images_right):
                self.index = 0
            if self.direction == 1:
                self.image = self.images_right[self.index]
            if self.direction == -1:
                self.image = self.images_left[self.index]

# add gravity
        self.vel_y += 1
        if self.vel_y > 10:
            self.vel_y = 10
        dy += self.vel_y


        # check for collision
        for tile in world.tile_list:
            #check for collsion in x direction
            if tile[1].colliderect(self.rect.x + dx, self.rect.y, self.width, self.height):
                dx = 0

            # collision in y direction
            if tile[1].colliderect(self.rect.x, self.rect.y + dy, self.width, self.height):
               #check if below ground i.e jumping
                if self.vel_y < 0:
                    dy = tile[1].bottom - self.rect.top
                    self.vel_y = 0
                # check if abive ground i.e falling
                elif self.vel_y >= 0:
                    dy = tile[1].top - self.rect.bottom
                    self.vel_y = 0

            # collesion with radiation

            # update player cordinates
        self.rect.x += dx
        self.rect.y += dy

        if self.rect.bottom > screen_height:
            self.rect.bottom = screen_height
            dy = 0

        # drow player on screen
        screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)


class Radiation(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        img = pygame.image.load('images/ra.png')
        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(img, (tile_size , tile_size ))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y


world_data = [
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0],
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],

]

player = player(950, 600)
rad_group = pygame.sprite.Group()
world = world(world_data)
# load imagies
bg_img = pygame.image.load('images/bg.jpg')
sc_img = pygame.image.load('images/scale.png')






run = True
while run:

    clock.tick(fps)
    screen.blit(bg_img, (0, 0))
    screen.blit(sc_img, (70, 20))
    world.drow()

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    player.update()
    pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
```

The traceback massage is:

```
C:\Users\dm864\PycharmProjects\gamecode\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/dm864/PycharmProjects/gamecode/main.py
pygame 2.1.2 (SDL 2.0.18, Python 3.10.2)
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\dm864\PycharmProjects\gamecode\venv\lib\site-packages\pygame\sprite.py", line 449, in add
    self.add(*sprite)
TypeError: pygame.sprite.AbstractGroup.add() argument after * must be an iterable, not type

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\dm864\PycharmProjects\gamecode\main.py", line 192, in <module>
    world = world(world_data)
  File "C:\Users\dm864\PycharmProjects\gamecode\main.py", line 45, in __init__
    rad_group.add(Radiation)
  File "C:\Users\dm864\PycharmProjects\gamecode\venv\lib\site-packages\pygame\sprite.py", line 462, in add
    sprite.add_internal(self)
TypeError: Sprite.add_internal() missing 1 required positional argument: 'group'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Do not give us instructions on how to answer your question.

Comment: *"i have no clue how to solve this issue in pygame"* is not an appropriate title for a question. The title should briefly describe what the question is about.

Answer (score 1):

`Radiation` is a class, but not an instance object of a sub class of `pygame.sprite.Sprite`. You have to add the instance object `rad`, instead of `Radiation`:

<s>`rad_group.add(Radiation)`</s>

```py
rad = Radiation(col_count * tile_size, row_count * tile_size)
rad_group.add(rad)
```